# Firebase getMessaging() throws FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

I used angular/fire cli to setup the project.

```js
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
        BrowserModule,
        CarouselModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        DpDatePickerModule,
        NgxScrollTopModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        GoogleMapsModule,
        provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
        provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
        provideMessaging(()=>getMessaging())
    ],
```

My imports look like this inside the app.module.ts . The error occurs when it tries to getMessaging().
Here is the entire error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (index.esm2017.js:479:29)
    at getMessagingInWindow (index.esm2017.js:1159:43)
    at angular-fire.js:227:48
    at angular-fire.js:160:59
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:27349:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (angular-fire.js:160:35)
    at angular-fire.js:227:21
    at app.module.ts:137:42
```